# why infitinite loop in this programme?

Tags: c, infinite

```
scanf("%d",&uzunluk);

mesaj=(char*)malloc ((uzunluk+1)*sizeof(char));
for (i=0 ;i<uzunluk; i++)
{
    scanf(" %c",&mesaj[i]);
}

if (uzunluk%2==1)
{
    mesaj[uzunluk]='z';
}

for (i=0; i<=uzunluk+(uzunluk%2)-2; i+2)
{
    printf("   %c%c",mesaj[i],mesaj[i+1]);
}
```

The last `for` goes into infinite loop. I couldn't fix it.

For example, if the mesaj is: `youare`

It should print

`yo ua re`

If length is odd, maybe: `tonight`

`to ni gh tz`

But it keeps on infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Even i do not know why there are infinite loops in C.

Answer (score 2):

In the last `for` you do not increment `i`.

Perhaps you mean: `i+=2` ?

Comment: @heidiboynww `i + 2` just add `2`  to `i` but don't change `i` itself, Either you can do `i = i + 2`.

Comment: yes, but this i+2 value is not assigne to i. The i has same initial value everytime the loop iterates.

Comment: i+2 and i=i+2 are same?t

Comment: @heidiboynww **NO** not same, `i + 2` doesn't change `i` but `i = i + 2` and `i += 2` update `i`, To increment `i` you need assignment operation.

Answer (score 0):

Change you last for loop like this:

```
for(i=0;i<=uzunluk+(uzunluk%2)-2;i+=2)
```

instead of

```
 for(i=0;i<=uzunluk+(uzunluk%2)-2;i+2)
```

as presently the value of `i` after increment is not assigned back to `i` making it run infinitely.

Your `i + 2` is just adding 2 to `i` but it is not changing `i` and that is why it is running infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing i in the last for-loop. You incremental (the third field) in the for loop head is just calculating i + 2 and not storing it back. Replace i+2 with i+=2.

Cheers